# Regular Expression in HTML - UiPath

Tags: html, regex, uipath

I'm trying to identify "Animal or Bird" in red font using regular expression. The HTML tags will be as in below pattern

```
<font color = red><span> Animal</span></font>
```

I tried

```
<font(?=color=red)
```

this identifies whenever the font is red so I modified to identify animal or bird when font is red and this expression is not working.

font or the span can have additional parameter/styles but if Animal or Bird font is red that needs to be identified.

```
<font(?=color=red)+(?=Animal|Bird)
```

If I could get help it would be great

Comment: Regexes aren't really suitable for HTML parsing. Consider using library providing html parsing.

Comment: this is part of automation to identify red text for a specific words

Comment: @markalex It is UiPath. No way to use any parsers.

Comment: Try `<font\s+color\s*=\s*red(?:(?!</?font[>\s]).)*?(Animal|Bird)`

Comment: is it possible to give some information for each of the quantifiers

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for many, many years.

Comment: i was working with some old stuff infra so came across this ```<font>```

Answer (score 1):

For the one-off task and given regex is the only choice for you, you can use

```
<font\s+color\s*=\s*red(?:(?!</?font[>\s]).)*?(Animal|Bird)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBn2cY/1).

*Details*:

- `<font\s+color\s*=\s*red` - `<font color=red` text with one or more whitespaces between `font` and `color` and zero or more whitespaces on both ends of the `=` char
- `(?:(?!</?font[>\s]).)*?` - any one char other than line break chars, zero or more but as few occurrences, that does not start `<font` or `</font` tag char sequence.
- `(Animal|Bird)` - Capturing group 1: `Animal` or `Bird`.